# Помощь в структуре базы данных mysqli

Tags: php, mysql, sql, phpmyadmin, mysqli

нуждаюсь в совете либо в примере, как реализовать структуру бд, дл выполнения задачи.

Задача:
Вывести графиком количество переходов по партнерской ссылке пользователя.

**Что есть сейчас**

В бд есть таблица user в которой есть **столбец ref_link_go_cnt**, куда собственно и записываются количество переходов по ссылке. Как вы понимаете с таких данных график с датой и количеством переходов по определенной дате не вывести.

Собственно вопрос как лучше реализовать в базе запись подобных данных, что бы минимизировать нагрузку и количество информации.

Создать отдельную таблицу для этого дела?

или же использовать например **таблицу истории пользователя**, записывая в нее каждый новый переход, а потом устраивать выборку ?

Буду рад вашей помощи в моей ситуации. Спасибо

Comment: Нужна отдельная таблица, где хранятся (вар.1) пользователь, ссылка и штамп времени перехода, либо (вар.2) пользователь, ссылка, дата перехода и количество переходов на эту дату. Второй вариант предпочтительнее, потому что "размазывает" нагрузку от учёта (правда, ценой потенциальной незначительной неточности данных, но скорее всего пренебрежимо малой).

Comment: https://canvasjs.com/javascript-charts/

Comment: Благодарю Вас за отклик, я попробую это использовать

Answer (score 0):

Базу делаешь так, столбики

```
id|Url1 |Url2 |Date1   |date2

1 |User1|     |10.10.19|

2 |     |User2|        |15.10.19

3 |User3|     |17.10.19|
```

потом берешь код (convas) немного под тебя переделал
https://pastebin.com/aDsEp1jk
ну и потом для автоматизации массив дата сделать циклом

```
data: [{
        name: "User1",
        type: "spline",
        yValueFormatString: "#0.## шт.",
        showInLegend: true,
        dataPoints: [
            { x: new Date(2017,6,24), y: 31 },
            { x: new Date(2017,6,25), y: 31 },
            { x: new Date(2017,6,26), y: 29 },
            { x: new Date(2017,6,27), y: 29 },
            { x: new Date(2017,6,28), y: 31 },
            { x: new Date(2017,6,29), y: 30 },
            { x: new Date(2017,6,30), y: 29 }
        ]
```

Comment: Благодарю за предоставленный пример, а так же ссылку на библиотеки, я нахожусь почти у цели, лишись пока лишь заминки с алгоритмом скрипта php.

Спасибо

Comment: я тоже, в своё время делал график, могу скинуть пример завтра

Comment: Да, буду при много благодарен, ранее вовсе не имел с ними опыта, сейчас так сказать учусь

Comment: https://pastebin.com/fdk62NB5  вот тут часть кода немного другой график, может намекнёт как скобки обернуть, массивы итд. я ещё посмотрю на 3 линейный график может сооброжу, да давно это было)

Comment: Спасибо большое, разберу ваш пример, спасибо!